# How to make django QuerySet will dynamic filter?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a query that looks like this:

```
conditions={'sector': u'65', 'tax_type': u'cleaning', 'district': u'22'}
qs = Something.objects.filter(**conditions)
```

But there raise an error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

How can I make the dynamic queryset with dictionary contain the filter name and conditions in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `Something` is already a `QuerySet`

Just do

```
qs = Something.filter(**conditions)
```